# Solving concentration PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics

I'm working on a problem, which involves the concentration of magnetic particles which interact with a flow field and a magnetic field.

Derived by the classical convection diffusion equation, I want to solve the steady state concentration in the domain.

The PDE reads as follws: $$ 0 = \nabla \bullet (c \nabla \varphi  - c a_{mag}  \nabla H D  - \nabla c D  ( 1 + \frac{\nu c}{1- \nu c}))$$

Where c is the concentration of the particles;
$\varphi$ is a scalar field, describing the potential of the flow;
$a_{mag}$ is a constant with magnetic properties of the particles;
H is a scalar field, which is the magnetic field strength;
D is a constant describing the diffusion coefficient;
$\nu $ is also a constant, which is the maximum possible concentration of the particles due to their finite size.

The domain is rectangular with zero flux on two sides and inlet and outlet on the other two.

Is there a analytical solution $c(x,y)$ for this problem? My PDE class was some time ago so any general tips for solving this kind of problem is much appreciated.

Comment: By analytical, do you mean [real (or complex) analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Real_versus_complex_analytic_functions), or an explicit solution in terms of elementary functions? If the former, it would be necessary to know the nature of $H$ and $\phi$. If the latter, it would probably be necessary to have expressions for $H$ and $\phi$. In either case, knowing the boundary conditions will also be necessary. I should also mention that even in the best of circumstances, finding explicit solutions to nonlinear PDEs is very difficult.

Comment: @plutoro Thanks for the quick response! I'm trying to get to an explicit solution. $\phi$ is just linear in y-direction with value $\phi = v_0$ at $y = -l$ and $\phi = 0$ at $y = l$. H stems from a magnetic scalar potential u which is linear in y-direction, so $\nabla H = 0$ in the "bulk" region of the domain. Nevertheless, the magnetic field strength H is de-homogenized by a cylindrical wire in the center of the domain. The equations for the velocity and the magnetic field were solved using FEM (COMSOL). 1/2

Comment: The b.c. for the concentration itself are: $\frac{\partial c}{\partial y} = v_0 c_0$ at $y=-l$ (Neumann) and $c = c_0$ at $c = l$ (Dirichlet). At $x = -w$ and $x = w$ there is a zero flux condition in x-direction. w being the width of the rectangular domain and l the length 2/2

Comment: Sorry I meant  $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} = v_0$ at $y = -l$.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, but I think it is unlikely that an explicit solution can be found.